# CSS - Text align to left and right - multi lines

Tags: css, alignment

I'm a beginner in CSS and I don't manage to do what I need.

I want to display some text on the left and on the right on the same line, and then only on the right on a second line.

Here's a [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/R7LA2/) :

**HtML :**

```
<div class="myDiv">
    <p class="alignleft"> Text on the left.</p>
    <p class="alignright">Text on the right.</p>
    <p class="alignright2">Text on the right 2.</p>
</div>
<div class="myDiv">
    <p class="alignleft"> Text on the left.</p>
    <p class="alignright">Text on the right.</p>
    <p class="alignright2">Text on the right 2.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.myDiv{
    margin: 0 25% 10px 25%; 
    border-style: dashed;
    border-width: 1px;
}

.alignleft {
    float: left;
}

.alignright {
   float: right;
}
```

The "Text on the right2" should be under "Text on the right".

It should be very simple but like I said I'm a beginner...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this if it works as you need.

```
.alignright2 {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R7LA2/2/

Comment: this solution seems to work for me.. the only thing missing was a clear: .myDiv:after { content:""; display:block; clear:both; visibility:hidden;}

Answer (score 4):

This works [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sid_m/R7LA2/8/)

```
.alignleft {
    text-align:left;
}
.alignright {
    text-align:right;
}

.alignright2 {
    text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But the first "Text on the right" should be on the same line.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

**html**

```
<div class="myDiv">
    <p class="alignleft"> Text on the left.</p>        
    <p class="alignright">Text on the right.</p>
    <div style="clear:left;"></div>
    <p class="alignright2">Text on the right 2.</p>   
    <div style="clear:right;"></div>
</div>
<div class="myDiv">
    <p class="alignleft"> Text on the left.</p>
    <p class="alignright">Text on the right.</p>
    <div style="clear:left;"></div>
    <p class="alignright2">Text on the right 2.</p>
    <div style="clear:right;"></div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.myDiv{
    margin: 0 25% 10px 25%; 
    border-style: dashed;
    border-width: 1px;"
}

.alignleft {
    float: left;
}
.alignright {
    float: right;
}

.alignright2 {
    float:right;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R7LA2/12/)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
.alignright2 {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:50%;
}
```

[Fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/R7LA2/11/)

You can change the margin according to your text or you need to change your html by surroding right2 paragraph into a div.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
.alignright2 {
text-align:right;
clear:right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R7LA2/16/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding any more extra tags in your HMTL, alternate solution for your code.

Just change you css:

```
.myDiv{
    margin: 0 25% 10px 25%; 
    border-style: dashed;
    border-width: 1px;
    display:inline-block; // Newly added...
}

.alignleft {
    float: left;
}
.alignright {
    float: right;
}

.alignright2 {
    float:right;// Newly added...
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R7LA2/17/)

Comment: Thx. But all the text is on the same line in your example, unless I reduce the width of the area.